# How to create a unique path inside a sub graph using Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

This is kind of an extension to my earlier question to which I have not received any replies yet which is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731687/how-use-cypher-with-merge-to-create-a-unique-sub-graph-path)

I am trying to figure out how to create a graph like below
[image]

But instead I am ending up with

[image]

Issue is that the examples of MERGE I see are all based on Label and as label is kind of universal, it ends up picking up warehouses of Shipper 1 while creating shipper 2 as they have same names. Kind of same issue I have with date and month in the previous post.

my code in Neo4JClient would look somewhat like this (hand typed example here)

```
var qry = GraphClient.Cypher
                .Merge("(whse:Warehouse{ Name: {whseName}})")
                .OnCreate("whse").Set("whse= {newWhseData}")
                .With("whse")
                .Start(new { root = shipper2Node})
                .CreateUnique("(root)-[:HAS_WAREHOUSE]->(whse)")
                .WithParams(new { whseName = newWhse.Name, newWhseData= newWhse})
                .Return(whse => whse.Node<Warehouse>());
 var whseNode = qry.Results.Single();
```

I really need to ensure that i don't create a duplicate warehouses for the same shipper, and hence the use of Merge in my code, I understand that Merge and Match is replacing the Create Unique in 2.0

I apologize here for re-posting here, but I was not sure how else to get help.

Thanks in advance, Kiran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use create-unique for the sub-graph, but you're making a good point that we should take this into consideration when evolving `MERGE` to work with Paths

Something like:

```
var qry = GraphClient.Cypher
            .Start(new { root = shipper2Node})
            .CreateUnique("(root)-[:HAS_WAREHOUSE]->(whse Name: {whseName})")
            .Set("whse= {newWhseData}")
            .WithParams(new { whseName = newWhse.Name, newWhseData= newWhse})
            .Return(whse => whse.Node<Warehouse>());
```

Comment: How would this work, would it always overwrite the  whse with the newWhseData every time the query is executed? or will it only use set command when new node is being created.

Comment: @Kiran That would update the property every time.  If shipper2Node already exists, you could continue to use Merge if you could try to create a composite ID to identify the Warehouse by using Warehouse's name and an identifier of shipper2Node.